# Unpacking Tensor Products: Bridging Multilinearity to Linearity

Tags: soft-question, tensor-products, tensors

I'm exploring the concept of the tensor product of vector spaces and seeking motivation behind its definition. I've come across the idea that the tensor product can transform multilinear "objects" into linear ones, presumably through the universal property. Could you provide a fundamental example that vividly illustrates this transformation and helps me grasp the essence of the tensor product?

**Edit**
Maybe to put my question into prospective to help you answer it better, I would like to know what I should be thinking when I see $V\otimes W$ ?
For example, no matter the context I can think of the product $V\times W$ as pairs $(v,w)$, or the quotient $R/I$ as elements of the form $r+I$ where usually everything of the form $I$ is set to be zero.

Comment: You have to define tensor product for this question to make sense. If you use the universal property as a starting point, then this is just a definition.

Comment: Are you using tensors for a physics-related subject or more of an algebra-related subject?

Comment: Start with just bilinear. A bilinear function on a vector space is not linear. With respect to a basis, it is a homogeneous quadratic polynomial. Homogeneous means no terms of degree 1 or 0. The space of homogeneous quadratic polynomials is a vector space. Equivalently, the space of bilinear functions on a vector  space is a vector space. In that sense bilinear functions are linear objects.

Comment: @student91 I think it's more algebra-related; I am not sure as we also use differential and smooth objects, It's for complex geometry.

Comment: The basic concept of a tensor product is purely an algebraic one, a multlinear algebraic one to be more precise. However, it plays a fundamental role in differential geometry, as well as many areas of physics such as electromagnetism, general relativity, and solid mechanics.

Comment: @J.DeRo Assume I am familiar with the usual definitions. I want to know what I should be thinking when I see $\otimes $.

Answer (score 1):

For finite dimensional spaces $V$, $W$ generated by basis
$\{b_1,b_2,...,b_n\}$ and $\{c_1,c_2,...,c_m\}$ respectively
one construct its tensor product $V\otimes W$ as the vector space
generated by the objects $b_i\otimes c_j$ defined as follow.

For the free vector space generated by all elements of $V\times W$ we mean that each pair $(v_k,w_l)$ serve to write linear combinations
$$\sum_{kl}a^{kl}(v_k,w_l),$$
where $a^{kl}$ are scalars.
Such space is symbolized as $F(V\times W)$.

Now take $R$ subspace of $F(V\times W)$ which  is generated by the all elements of the form

i)$\qquad (r_1+r_2, s)-(r_1,s)-(r_2,s)$

ii)$\qquad (r, s_1+s_2)-(r,s_1)-(r,s_2)$

iii)$\qquad k(r, s)-(kr,s)$

iv)$\qquad k(r, s)-(r,ks)$

for all $r,r_1,r_2\in V$ , $s, s_1,s_2\in W$ and all $k\in\mathbb F$.

Then it is defined $V\otimes W=F(V\times W)/R$, the quotient vector space. This gives that
the elements are cosets
$$r\otimes s=(r,s)+R.$$

In particular the elements $b_i\otimes c_j$ will generate any other
element in $V\otimes W$.

Now, each *bilinear* map $\mathbf Q:V\times W\to\mathbb F$ can be represented
by $\mathbf Q(v,w)=v^{\top}Qw$ being this last expression the matrix multiplication of $v,Q,w$ of respective components.

But each matrix $Q$ can be decomposed as a
(bi-indexed) linear combination
$$Q=\sum_{kl}Q_{kl}E^{kl}$$
where the $E^{kl}$ are elementary matrices with an $1$ in the $kl$
entry and zeroes elsewhere.
Then the induced
$L^{kl}:V\otimes W\to\mathbb F$ via
$$L^{kl}(b_i\otimes c_j)=b_i^{\top}E^{kl}c_j=\delta^k_i\delta^l_j,$$
and
then the *linear* map $L_{\mathbf Q}:V\otimes W\to \mathbb F$ via
$$L_{\mathbf Q}(v\otimes w)=\sum_{kl}Q_{kl}L^{kl}(v\otimes w),$$
will comply
$$\mathbf Q(v,w)=L_{\mathbf Q}(v\otimes w).$$