How specifically do tensor products reduce multilinear algebra to linear algebra
I understand the advantages of dealing with linear systems, and that bilinear or multi-linear objects are different from linear objects.
I understand that the construction of a tensor product between vector spaces transforms a multilinear object to a linear object, and this has to do with a "universal property".
Can I have an example of this transformation at work, as for instance, in the case of the determinant or the dot product, or other conceptual or concrete explanation of how this works?

It's really a trick of perspective. The tensor product is designed so that multilinear maps $V\times V\times\cdots\times V\to \mathbb{F}$ become linear maps $V\otimes V\otimes V\otimes\cdots\otimes V\to\mathbb{F}$.

@Neal Yes, but how does the "magic" happen?

Good explanation: https://youtu.be/vZzZhdLC_YQ?si=0RjPlb4l_rf4C0yk

It occurs to me that you might be asking a simpler question than I thought, so let's discuss concretely how the identification between multilinear and linear maps works in a small example.
Take $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and let's consider the dot product as a bilinear map $\cdot : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$, as you suggested. If we write $e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ for the standard basis of $V$ then the dot product is given explicitly on this basis by
$$e_1 \cdot e_1 = e_2 \cdot e_2 = 1, e_1 \cdot e_2 = e_2 \cdot e_1 = 0.$$
or in short $e_i \cdot e_j = \delta_{ij}$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. The idea of the tensor product is that this specification of what a bilinear map is doing on pairs of basis vectors is really "the same as" specifying what a corresponding linear map is doing on a vector space with basis given by the tensors $e_1 \otimes e_1, e_1 \otimes e_2, e_2 \otimes e_1, e_2 \otimes e_2$. That is, the dot product corresponds to a linear map
$$D : V \otimes V \to \mathbb{R}$$
and this linear map does the following: $V \otimes V$ has a basis of tensor products as mentioned above, and
$$D(e_1 \otimes e_1) = D(e_2 \otimes e_2) = 1, D(e_1 \otimes e_2) = D(e_2 \otimes e_1) = 0$$
This linear map $D$ contains exactly the same information as the bilinear dot product. The tensor product is exactly designed so that in general we have $D(v \otimes w) = v \cdot w$.
$D$ is itself, in turn, equivalent to an element of the tensor product $V^{\ast} \otimes V^{\ast}$, so it is a tensor of type $(0, 2)$. Explicitly, if we write $f_1, f_2 \in V^{\ast}$ for the dual basis of $e_1, e_2$ (I am not going to use the dot product to identify $V$ with its dual because I think that would be confusing here), so that $f_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$, then $D$ corresponds to the element
$$D^{\ast} = f_1 \otimes f_1 + f_2 \otimes f_2.$$

Part of what's tricky to understand about tensors is that a tensor can be interpreted as a function in multiple different ways. For example the dot product is, simultaneously, identified with

a linear map $V \otimes V \to \mathbb{R}$,
a linear map $V \to V^{\ast}$ (the induced isomorphism from $V$ to its dual, which here sends $e_i$ to $f_i$), and
a linear map $\mathbb{R} \to V^{\ast} \otimes V^{\ast}$

and we need to make use of all of these descriptions in general. It takes time and experience to get comfortable with this.

Another silly example would be as follows? for $v=[2,2], w=[1,3]$ the area subtended could be given by $\omega=1 dx \wedge dy$, which  acting on $\omega(v,w)= \det\begin{bmatrix}2&2\1&3\end{bmatrix}=4.$ The linear operations are $2\cdot 3 dx^1\wedge dy^2 - 2 \cdot 1 dy^1 \wedge dx^2$, or as a tensor $1 e^1\otimes e^2 - 1e^2 \otimes e^1 + 0 e^1 \otimes e^1 + 0 e^2 \otimes e^2$. Linear in each tensored entry, but bilinear overall. Yes?

@JAP: I'm not quite sure what you're calculating or where all these expressions live. You say "the linear operations" - which linear operations? You've picked two specific vectors $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and computed some version of their wedge product $v \wedge w \in \Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Writing $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ you can think of this wedge product as an element of $V^{\otimes 2}$. Are you trying to compute this element?

You showed how the dot product (bilinear) can be transformed into a linear operation, and I wanted to apply that to the determinant as used in the calculation of the signed area of the parallelogram between two vectors. I believe this trivial exercise is the idea behind the wedge product, and I was trying to express it both as elementary linear operations in a 2-form, and as a tensor in which each entry, e.g. $e^1\otimes e^2$ is linear. It was just a way to replicate the idea for the dot product.

@JAP: okay, so your question is not about the specific wedge product $v \wedge w$ but about how to think of the wedge product itself as a bilinear map in this language? First there's a small subtlety here: the wedge product does not take values in $\mathbb{R}$ but in $\Lambda^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, which is $1$-dimensional but does not come with a preferred basis. Choosing such a basis amounts to choosing an "oriented volume form" on $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can ignore this small subtlety by just working concretely with the determinant as a bilinear function on column vectors. (Cont.)

This bilinear function is $\det \begin{bmatrix} a & c \ b & d \end{bmatrix} = ad - bc$ so, as a tensor in $V^{\ast} \otimes V^{\ast}$, it can be identified with $f_1 \otimes f_2 - f_2 \otimes f_1$ (and we don't need to write the other two coefficients because they're $0$), which is what you wrote (I assume the upper index notation refers to the dual basis).

Generalizing this to the determinant as a multilinear function on $n$ column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ produces a tensor whose coefficients in the dual basis are given by the Levi-Civita symbol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol

Thank you very much. I read it as I am hovering over the concept of multi-linear to linear transformation via tensor products approximately, but messing up some technical aspects, such as the subscript versus superscript in $f_1 \otimes f_2 - f_2 \otimes f_1$ (correct) and $1 e^1\otimes e^2 - 1e^2 \otimes e^1$ (my attempt).

The superscript vs. subscript doesn't matter (as long as $e^i$ still refers to the dual basis), those are equivalent. I prefer not to use superscripts because they collide notationally with exponents although sometimes they seem like the nicest option.

I picture now the whole process as breaking down a bloc of granite (matrix / bi-linear form) into individual grains of quartz ($e_i\otimes e^j$ basis elementary tensors): in matrix form, it is impossible to change a row (dual) by linear algebra operations without affecting all the columns (hence bi-linear), but when each entry has its own tensored basis $e_i\otimes e^j$ applied to it, we can dial (linear change) each one independent of the others by basic linear algebra operations - hence, it becomes linearlized.

Sure, you can think of it like that. One way to say it is that all of the bilinearity has been shoved into the tensor product.

A bilinear map $Q:V\times V\to\mathbb F$ in a finite dimensional vector space can be characterized with a square matrix.
Any matrix can be described as a linear combination of elementary ones
$E^{ij}$ which are matrices with all zero entries safe the entry $ij$, and the mention entry with a $1$.
This is $$Q=\sum_{ij}Q_{ij}E^{ij}$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
Q(v,w)&=&\sum_{ij}Q_{ij}E^{ij}(v,w),\\
&=&\sum_{ij}Q_{ij}v^iw^j.
\end{eqnarray*}
That is: bi-linearity of $Q$  employs linearity to use the bi-linearity of basis $E^{ij}$'s.

For the usual inner product one chooses $Q=1!!1$. For general inner product one must choose a symmetric, non-negatively defined and  non-degenerated square matrix.

Observe that $$1!!1=E^{11}+E^{22}+\cdots+E^{nn}.$$

Thank you! The matrices $E^{ij}$, which could have a form such as for example $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\0&0&1\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ are the equivalent of the tensor basis vectors, such as $e^2\otimes e^3$? with $Q_{ij}$ being the coefficients of the tensor?

The sentence "bi-linearity of $Q$ employs linearity to use the bi-linearity of basis $E_{ij}$'s." is really loaded :-) I am not sure I get it. But I wish I did since it probably encapsulates the best intuition.

When $\dim V=2$ for any bilinear we've $$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
Q_{11}&Q_{12}\\Q_{21}&Q_{22}
\end{array}
\right]=
Q_{11}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\0&0
\end{array}
\right]
+
Q_{12}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0&1\\0&0
\end{array}
\right]
+
Q_{21}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0&0\\1&0
\end{array}
\right]
+
Q_{22}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0&0\\0&1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

@JAP  here is where you see that bilinearity of $Q$ depends on the linear combination $$Q=Q_{11}E^{11}+Q_{12}E^{12}+Q_{21}E^{21}+Q_{22}E^{22},$$ and $E^{ij}$ is the matrix for the basis bilinears $e^i\otimes e^j$, yeah!

@JAP take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4851118/unpacking-tensor-products-bridging-multilinearity-to-linearity/4851794#4851794

The "magic" (at least if I am reading the question correctly) is in the universal property, or may the point is that the multilinearity is still there, it is just packaged neatly in one place:
I'll work over the real numbers $\mathbb R$, but the choice of field is not important. If $V$ and $W$ are real vector spaces, then $V\otimes W$ is, informally speaking, the vector space of products of pairs of elements of $V$ and $W$, where we require a "product" to be $\mathbb R$-bilinear.
Making this a little more precise, suppose we have a bilinear map $t\colon V\times W \to U$, where $U$ is again an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Let $B_V$ and $B_W$ be bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively, then if $v \in V$ and $w \in W$, then $v = \sum_{b \in B_V} \lambda_b b$ and $w = \sum_{d \in B_W} \mu_d d$, and
$$
\begin{split}
t(v,w) &= t(\sum_{b\in B_V} \lambda_b b, \sum_{d \in B_W}\mu_d d) \\
&= \sum_{b\in B_V}\lambda_b t(b,\sum_{d \in  B_W} \mu_d d) \\
&= \sum_{b \in B_V,d\in B_W} \lambda_b \mu_d t(b,d)
\end{split}
\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
So that $t$ is encoded in the array $(t(b,d))_{b \in B_V,d\in B_W}$, which is usually known as the "Gram matrix" of $t$ (at least with $U=\mathbb R$). Now this means that giving a bilinear map $V\times W \to U$ is equivalent to giving a function $t'\colon B_V\times B_W \to U$.
Now if I let $T$ be the vector space of formal linear combinations of the elements of $B_V\times B_W$, then $t'$ extends uniquely to a linear map $\tilde{t}\colon T \to U$, and we can replace the multilinear map $t$ with the linear map $\tilde{t}\colon T \to U$, provided that we remember how we  associate to $\tilde{t}$ the multilinear map $t$. In other words, we need to capture the calculation we did in ($\dagger$) above.
One neat way to do that is to notice that $T$ is the target of a bilinear map $m\colon V\times W \to T$, where $m(v,w) = \sum_{b \in B_V,d\in B_W} \lambda_b \mu_d (b,d)$ (this is essentially just checking that any Gram matrix determines a bilinear map) and clearly, $(\dagger)$ shows that any bilinear map $t$ satisfies $t = \tilde{t}\circ m$, and indeed it is easy to see that $\tilde{t}$ is uniquely determined by the condition that $\tilde{t}\circ m = t$
Thus the map $m\colon V\times W \to T$ is a bilinear map from which any other bilinear map is obtained by composing with a linear map from $T$, and so we have reduced studying bilinear maps from $V\times W$ to studying linear maps from $T$ as long as you remember that $T$ is the target of a natural bilinear map from $V\times W$.
The pair $(T,m)$ is normally written $(V \otimes W,\otimes)$, and this is exactly what the tensor product does: it packages the multilinearity in a single, universal, product -- the tensor product -- from which all multilinear maps are obtained by composition with a linear map.
The important thing to note here is that the tensor product should not be thought of as just the vector space $T$, but rather as that vector space viewed as the target of a bilinear map from the original vector spaces $V$ and $W$. Indeed as long as one remembers that map, it is easy to see that the tensor product does not depend on the choice of bases $B_V$ and $B_W$ that we made to begin with: If $T'$ is the formal linear span of pairs $(b',d')$ for $b'$ and $d'$ elements of some other bases $B_V'$ and $B_W'$ of $V$ and $W$ respectively, then if $m'\colon V\times W \to T'$ is the associated bilinear map, then we have $m'= \tilde{m}'\circ m$ and $m =\tilde{m}\circ m'$, so that $m = \tilde{m}\circ m' = \tilde{m}\tilde{m}'\circ m$. But now $m=\text{id}_T \circ m$ and so the universal property (for $m$ applied to the bilinear map $m$) shows $\tilde{m}\tilde{m}' = \text{id}_T$. Similarly $\tilde{m}'\circ\tilde{m} = \text{id}_{T'}$, so that $\tilde{m}$ and $\tilde{m}'$ give canonical isomorphisms between $T$ and $T'$.
Addendum: The construction of the tensor product using bases for $V$ and $W$ is not the only possible approach. Another method which is described in many textbooks is the following: If $V$ and $W$ are vector space, let $V*W$ be the vector space of all formal linear combinations of pairs $[v,w]$ where $v \in V$ and $w \in W$. Then let $R$ be the subspace of $V*W$ spanned by
$$
\mathcal R = \begin{split}
\{[v_1+v_2,w]-[v_1,w]-&[v_2,w],
[v,w_1+w_2]-[v,w_1]-[v,w_2], \\
\lambda[v,w]-[\lambda v,w]&, 
 \lambda[v,w]-[v,\lambda w]: v,v_1,v_2 \in V, w,w_1,w_2 \in W, \lambda \in \mathbb R\}
\end{split}
$$
where $v,v_1,v_2 \in V; w,w_1,w_2 \in W, \lambda \in \mathbb R$. Let $Q=V*W/R$ and let $q\colon V*W \to Q$ be the quotient map, and let $t\colon V\times W \to Q$ be the map given by $t(v,w) = q([v,w])$. Then the subspace $R$ was defined precisely so that $t$ is bilinear, and moreover, if $b\colon V\times W \to U$ is function, then, since they form a basis of $V*W$ there is a unique linear map $b'\colon V*W \to U$ given by setting $b'([v,w]) = b(v,w)$ and extending linearly. Now $b$ is bilinear precisely when $b'$ maps all of the elements of $\mathcal R$, and hence the subspace $R$, to $0\in U$. Thus $b'$ induces a linear map $\tilde{b}\colon Q \to U$ such that $\tilde{b}\circ q = b'$ precisely when $b$ is bilinear. But then it is easy to see that $(Q,t)$ satisfies the universal property: for any bilinear map $b$ there is a unique linear map $\tilde{b}$ such that $b = \tilde{b}\circ t$ where, as above, $t\colon V\times W \to Q$ is the map $t(v,w) = q[v,w]$.
It may be useful to compare this quotient construction with the construction uses bases above: if $B_V$ and $B_W$ are bases of $V$ and $W$ respectively, then the vector space $T$ is just the subspace of $V*W$ spanned by $\{[b,d]: b \in B_V, d \in B_W\}$, and you can check that $q\colon V*W\to Q$ restricts to an isomorphism from $T$ to $Q$, and $m = (q_{|T}^{-1})\circ t$. This gives another way of seeing that the spaces you obtain using different bases are isomorphic, as they are all isomorphic to $Q$.
Although it is more abstract, the quotient construction of the tensor product has other advantages also -- for example it can be used to show the existence of tensor products of modules over a ring.

I have re-read several times your answer (also upvoted it initially), and still struggling with it. Would it be correct to say that the linearization has nothing to do with the quotient-ing of the formal product of $V \star W$ by the span of multilinear relations? And to state instead that it is strictly related to the universal property?

More concrete follow-up question: I am not sure I understand your expression $(V \otimes W,\otimes)$.

@JAP -- I'll try and answer your questions in order: It is the universal property that gives the linearization, as you say. The quotienting you refer to is, I think, part of a construction of the tensor product, i.e. part of (one way) of establishing that the tensor product exists: Given $V$ and $W$ you can form the vector space $V*W$ with basis the set of pairs $(v,w)$ where $v\in V, w\in W$, and then take the quotient of this space by the multi-linear relations. The fact that that quotient then satisfies the universal property shows it is a construction of the tensor product.

@JAP -- the notation $(V\otimes W,\otimes)$ just means the vector space $V\otimes W$ together with the bilinear map $(v,w)\mapsto v\otimes w$. I guess people don't tend to name this bilinear map explicitly as a function $\otimes \colon V\times W \to V\otimes W$, but it seemed unnecessarily cumbersome to introduce a new symbol for it. Sorry if that caused confusion!

I just updated my answer to add a discuss of the quotient construction -- hopefully that will help with the question you asked in your first comment.
